# How is flagellar movement controlled?

Tags: cell-biology

How does a cell control the movement of flagella? Both the rotatory movements and sideways movements helps the cell to move. How are these flagellar movements controlled ? It is through the regulation of the proteins flagellin and tubulin? I want to know the mechanism for both prokaryotic and eukaryotic flagella ?

Comment: No its not a homework question I know the rules of homework questions

Comment: Can you expand a little bit: What do you mean by how are they controlled? Response to stimulus or the biomechanical aspects? Note that the bacterial flagella is different from the eukaryotic flagella. Please clarify which one you are interested in.